# FindWindow vs GetActiveWindow - Why do they return differnt handles?

Tags: c#, findwindow

Anyone have an idea why this wouldn't work?

```
IntPtr hWnd = FindWindow(null, "Calculator");
IntPtr hWnd2 = GetActiveWindow();

if(hWnd == hWnd2)
{
     MessageBox.Show("Same");
}
```

Invokes are:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetActiveWindow();

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
```

Comment: how are you ensuring the active window is Calculator when you run the application?

Comment: I'm clicking on it with the mouse lol?  I figured it out adding an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's very possible that GetActiveWindow() is returning the handle to your application/command window.

Comment: This is correct - `GetActiveWindow` returns a reference to the calling thread's active window. Docs here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646292.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Ends up "GetActiveWindow" seems to be returning child areas.

GetForegroundWindow() is returning the windows handle.